# How do I convert an ORC dataframe in Spark to something else?

Tags: apache-spark, orc

I have a dataset I've read in from hive/orc in Spark, but I'm getting all kinds of errors I did not get when reading in from a csv. How can I tell spark to convert that dataset to something that's not orc without hitting the disk? Right now I'm using this:

```
FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration).delete(new Path(name));
loadedTbl.write.json(name);
val q = hc.read.json(name);
```

Comment: Edit your question to include an MCVE code and the exceptions you are seeing. Read this for information on creating an MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm not sure why there should be a difference if the dataset originate from ORC or a csv, what kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: From your question it appears that you want to convert a file from ORC to some other format. However, you mention that you do not want to hit the disk. Either of my takes must be false, can you clarify this? It would probably make replying easier. If your aim is just reading the file, perhaps you may share additional details, so that people can more easily help you. Things like the version of Spark you are using, the errors the you get, whether your file backs a Hive table or not and so on.

Comment: Care to elaborate on the errors in _"I have a dataset I've read in from hive/orc in Spark, but I'm getting all kinds of errors"_. Edit your question and add the errors. The more the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite to any format and use it.

```
df.write.json('json_file_name')
df.write.parquet('parquet_file_name')
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this but avoid hitting the disk?